# Replacement of LdapURL class in java 11

Tags: ldap, java-11

I was using LdapURL class like below using Java 8, now I have upgraded to java 11 so I need replacement of this class.

```
LdapURL ldapURL = new LdapURL(ldapDomain);
if (!ldapURL.useSsl()) {
    profiles.add("non-secure-LDAP");
} else {
    profiles.add("secure-LDAP");
}
```

Could someone help.

Comment: What does this `new LdapURL(ldapDomain).useSsl()` do, effectively? Anything more than `ldapDomain.startsWith("ldaps:")` or `ldapDomain.regionMatches(true, 0, "ldaps:", 0, 6)`?

Comment: Right Holger I analyzed it thoroughly and startsWith method actually solves the purpose